# Multiple Edit forms in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've got a form that gets filled out in stages so I wanted to direct users to a secondary edit form part way through the process. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hide and reveal using JQuery on the editform.aspx would be my initial choice. I've done this type of work for a very well known bank and it worked very well. Single form with different sections of the form to fill in dependant on the answers provided (and the user group membership)

If you actually want to maintain two lists and hence two forms and redirect between the two - I would look into changing the "source" querystring parameter in the editform so that on completion of the form, you get directed to an alternate location. Not tried it but it would be a sensible place to start looking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I thought about doing jQuesry, but ended up getting SharePoint conditional formatting to work.

Comment: Just a note: Redirecting to a different form and referencing the newly created item's ID can be tricky and depends on javascript. See this handy function from spservices: [$().SPServices.SPRedirectWithID](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPRedirectWithID&referringTitle=Documentation). And this function depends on "get last item created by current id" _workaround_.

Comment: I'd forgotten about that one. SPServices has got me out of jail many times.